# Getting 404 Not Found when doing a jira search for project

Tags: jira, jersey-client

I am trying to learn RESTFul web services using Jersey

I have written some java code to return the json for a JIRA search for a project ID, the code is based on that created by Bernd Hort (BP206 at connect2014)

```
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        HTTPBasicAuthFilter authFilter = new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("username", "password");
        client.addFilter(authFilter);
        WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

        String searchquery = "search?jql=id=" + id + "&maxResults=5000";
        System.out.println("Query=" + searchquery);

        String json = service.path(searchquery).accept(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

I have tested the search using both Postman and putting it into the browser url and it returns data.

```
http://myserver:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=id=12408&maxResults=5000
```

when I try it in my java code I get the following error;

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://myserver:8080/rest/api/2/search%3Fjql=id=12408&maxResults=5000 returned a response status of 404 Not Found
```

it seems to be changing the '?' to '%3f' which the search doesn't like

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying that query as part of the path, so it's being escaped as such:

```
String json = service.path(searchquery).accept(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

You want to make it a query parameter:

```
String json = service.path("search")
            .queryParam("jql", "id=" + id)
            .queryParam("maxResults", "5000)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```